# Question wrongly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Please look this question,

[How to decrement dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978016/how-to-decrement-dates)

in above question OP asked for tags sql, sql-server, datetime, and  decrement,and question marked as duplicate by marc_s, JqueryKing, t-clausen.dk to

[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

in above case question was related to SQL or SQL server and marked duplicate as javascript..

is this correct??

Comment: It is an incredibly clumsy question.  It was certainly a duplicate the way it was originally asked.  That the dup did not help him is not terribly surprising, removing the [jquery] tag however accomplished absolutely nothing. It is entirely up to the OP to do a better job describing what he *really* wants, SO is not a site where psychics hand out free advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no - it *is* a duplicate, but a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server).

Note that the question originally contained [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) as one of the tags, that is probably why the JavaScript question got selected as the original.